# Dual Loops in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this loop where the indices in the loop change at the same time.

```
For i = 0 To 20 Step 5
For j = 0 To 5 Step 1

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + i, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + j)

Next i
Next j
```

I am trying to get the loop to do this

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 0, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 0)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 5, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 1)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 10, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 2)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 15, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 3)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 20, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 4)
```

The loop I have unfortuantly does this:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 0, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 0)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 5, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 0)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 10, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 0)
...
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 0, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 1)
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + 5, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + 1)
```

I guess I can have a single loop such that: But that doesn't quite do it.

```
For i = 0 To 20 Step 5

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + i, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + j-4)

Next j
```

Can anyone suggest any ideas for having a loop where the indicies are changing concurrently at the same time? Thank you!!

Comment: I think the problem is "Next i
Next j"  I think you mess it up, should be "Next j Next i"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want them to run in parallel, you actually don't want two loops. Calculate one variable from the other:

```
For j = 0 To 4 Step 1
  i = j * 5

  Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + i, 0)).Copy Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + j)

Next i
```

Comment: Your loop is different that OP's.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: If you mean that `j` runs from `0` to `4`, then it is on purpose. Otherwise it wouldn't produce the desired result. In the original code the outer loop does five iterations and the inner loop does six iterations, but from the result you see that they should both do five iterations, and also as they should run in parallel they have to run the same number of iterations.

Answer (score 2):

```
for j = 0 to 5
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(5 + i, 0)).Copy _
         Destination:=Cells(8, 12 + j)
    i = i + 5
next j
```

Edit: To make my answer a bit more complete: nested for loops do not "work concurrently". The inner-most for loop does every iteration, ends and then the next loop can finish its cycle and so on. The trick to what you are doing is only one loop which controls both variables. You can choose whichever you want to put in your look (either i and manually increment j or the other way around).